# Polar Decomposition for bounded operators on Hilbert spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

In the book "An introduction to operator algebra" by Kehe Zhu, I have a question.
https://books.google.co.th/books?id=XHLj7bz8hOIC&lpg=PP1&dq=an%20introduction%20to%20operator%20algebra%20Polar%20Decomposition&hl=th&pg=PA75#v=onepage&q=an%20introduction%20to%20operator%20algebra%20Polar%20Decomposition&f=false

In the prove of uniqueness part of Theorem 12.8, \begin{align*}
P^2 &= T^*T &\quad \text{(definition of P)}\\
    &= QW^*WQ &\quad \text{(by assumption)}\\
   &= Q^2. &\quad \text{(Why???)}
\end{align*}

Comment: One typically shows the following first: If $A \ge 0$, then there exists a unique $P \ge 0$ such that $P^{2}=A$. That's how they are concluding that $P=Q$.

Comment: I understand it but I don't understant that $W^*W$ is projection onto $(\ker W)^\bot $ why we can conclude that $P^2 = Q^2$.

Comment: For $P$ (or $Q$), $X=\mathcal{N}(P)\oplus\mathcal{R}(P)^{c}$ ('c' for closure.) $P$ and $Q$ must have the same null spaces, with $\mathcal{N}(P)=\mathcal{N}(P^{2})=\mathcal{N}(A)$, which follows because $P^{2}x=0$ gives $(P^{2}x,x)=(Px,Px)=\|Px\|^{2}=0$ and, hence, $\mathcal{N}(P^{2})=\mathcal{N}(P)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T\in\mathcal{B}(H)$, then $T^{\star}T \ge 0$ has a unique positive square root $P$. This $P$ commutes with every operator that commutes with $T^{\star}T$. And,
\begin{align}
       \|Tx\|^{2}=(Tx,Tx) & =(T^{\star}Tx,x)\\
                          & =(P^{2}x,x)=(Px,Px)=\|Px\|^{2}.
\end{align}
So there is a unique linear operator $V : \mathcal{R}(P)^{c}\rightarrow \mathcal{R}(T)$ such that $Tx=VPx$, but $V$ is not determined at all on
$$
        \mathcal{R}(P)^{\perp} = \mathcal{N}(P)=\mathcal{N}(T).
$$
So it customary to extended $V$ to be $0$ on $\mathcal{R}(P)^{\perp}=\mathcal{N}(P)$. That defines $V$ uniquely on
$$
                  \mathcal{N}(P)\oplus\mathcal{R}(P)^{c}=H.
$$
$V$ is $0$ on $\mathcal{N}(P)$ and is isometric on $\mathcal{R}(P)^{c}=\mathcal{N}(P)^{\perp}$.

Now suppose that $Q \ge 0$, that $W$ is a partial isometry that is $0$ on $\mathcal{N}(Q)=\mathcal{R}(Q)^{\perp}$, and that $T=WQ$. Then $\|Wq\|=\|q\|$ for all $q \in \mathcal{R}(Q)$. Hence $W^{\star}W=I$ on $\mathcal{R}(Q)$; we already know $W^{\star}W=0$ on $\mathcal{R}(Q)^{\perp}=\mathcal{N}(Q)$. Therefore,
$$
                P^{2}=T^{\star}T=QW^{\star}WQ = Q^{2},\\
                     \implies P=Q.
$$
Therefore, $T = VP=WQ =WP$ implies $Vp=Wp$ for all $p\in\mathcal{R}(Q)^{c}$, while $Vp=Wp=0$ for $p \in \mathcal{N}(T)=\mathcal{N}(P)=\mathcal{N}(Q)$. So $V=W$.